# Combine Two identical jQuery functions except they use different selectors and classes

Tags: jquery

I have two functions that do the same thing, except the element I am targeting is different and so is the ID I want to add. What is the best way to combine these into a single function?

```
  <script>
      $('.Index-page--has-image[id*="angle-right"]').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).index('.Index-page--has-image')
        $('.Parallax-host .Parallax-item').eq(index).attr('id','angle-right');
      });
        $('.Index-page--has-image[id*="angle-left"]').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).index('.Index-page--has-image')
        $('.Parallax-host .Parallax-item').eq(index).attr('id','angle-left');
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['left','right'].forEach( way => {
    way = 'angle-' + way ;
    $('.Index-page--has-image[id*="'+way+'"]').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).index('.Index-page--has-image');
        $('.Parallax-host .Parallax-item').eq(index).attr('id',way);
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the function outside the JQ `each` function, and pass the `angle` value to the function parameter, like this

```
function yourFunctionName(element, idValue){
  let index = $(element).index('.Index-page--has-image')
  $('.Parallax-host .Parallax-item').eq(index).attr('id', idValue);
}
 $('.Index-page--has-image[id*="angle-right"]').each(function(){
     yourFunctionName(this, 'angle-right');
  });
  $('.Index-page--has-image[id*="angle-left"]').each(function(){
     yourFunctionName(this, 'angle-left');
  });
```

Comment: Is this slightly more performant than what I had? I assumed combining them would be beneficial somehow.